# How to identify type that causes issue No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, nopcommerce

I'm working with NopCommerce where for DI Autofac is used. There are lots of services and sometimes cyclic dependencies may take place which causes error:

***No parameterless constructor defined for this object.***

It's quite difficult to find out which services have cyclic dependencies, how to catch the type which can't be instantiated due to cyclic dependency or other reason?

1. Error example,

CustomerController at Nop.Web.Controllers, has many services injected:

**region c-tor**

```
     public CustomerController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService,
            IDateTimeHelper dateTimeHelper,
            DateTimeSettings dateTimeSettings, 
            TaxSettings taxSettings,
            ILocalizationService localizationService,
            IWorkContext workContext,
            IStoreContext storeContext,
            ICustomerService customerService,
            IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService,
            ....
            etc.)
        {
            this._authenticationService = authenticationService;
            this._dateTimeHelper = dateTimeHelper;
            this._dateTimeSettings = dateTimeSettings;
            this._taxSettings = taxSettings;
            this._localizationService = localizationService;
            this._workContext = workContext;
            this._storeContext = storeContext;
            this._customerService = customerService;
            this._genericAttributeService = genericAttributeService;
            ....
            etc.
          }
```

**end region**

some of services to be initialized, or I don't know, requires VPN connection, when I'm disconnected i get the following error:

[image]

This error tells nothing, i may guess which service wasn't initialized and where the problem is until i noticed that VPN is disconnected.

The same kind of error message i get when there are some cyclic references between services, i'll add an example and stack trace later, when meet such problem again.

Comment: This error message doesn't look like an *Autofac* error message but an *EntityFramework* error message. Do you have a stack trace ?

Comment: Maybe there is a tool that will help but whenever I run into this I just start commenting services out of the constructor and re-running until I identify the offender.  Once you find that you need to get into that service's constructor to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a helper that allows to identify which service couldn't be resolved:

```
public static class ControllerActivatorHelper
{
    public static string TestCreateController(string controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            var type = TryGetType(controllerType);
            if (type == null)
                return "Can't find type " + controllerType;
            return TestCreateController(type);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private static Type TryGetType(string typeName)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null) return type;
        foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = a.GetType(typeName);
            if (type != null)
                return type;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Parameterless Constructor Error is quite difficult to indentify what service is missing in dependencies registration
    /// this is a helper method allows to see the log of resolving types for each c-tor argument
    /// </summary>
    public static string TestCreateController(Type controllerType)
    {
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        DefaultControllerActivator activator = new DefaultControllerActivator();
        log.AppendFormat("<h2>Inspecting type '{0}'</h2>", controllerType.FullName);
        if (activator.CanCreate(controllerType) == false)
        {
            var ctors = controllerType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            List<Type> inspectedTypes = new List<Type>();
            bool anyFail = false;
            foreach (var ctor in ctors)
            {
                var parameters = ctor.GetParameters();
                foreach (var parameterInfo in parameters)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!inspectedTypes.Contains(parameterInfo.ParameterType))
                        {
                            log.AppendLine("<br/>");
                            inspectedTypes.Add(parameterInfo.ParameterType);
                            log.AppendFormat("Resolving {0} {1}..", parameterInfo.ParameterType.Name,
                                parameterInfo.Name);
                            var resolvedType = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(parameterInfo.ParameterType);
                            log.AppendFormat(" SUCCESS. Resolved type is '{0}'", resolvedType.GetType().FullName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Append(" <strong>FAILED</strong>");
                        log.AppendLine("<p><strong>Error:</strong>" + ex.Message + "<p/>");
                        anyFail = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!anyFail)
            {
                //inspect fields
                var fields = controllerType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!inspectedTypes.Contains(fieldInfo.FieldType))
                        {
                            log.AppendLine("<br/>");
                            inspectedTypes.Add(fieldInfo.FieldType);
                            log.AppendFormat("Resolving {0} {1}..", fieldInfo.FieldType.Name, fieldInfo.Name);
                            var resolvedType = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(fieldInfo.FieldType);
                            log.AppendFormat(" SUCCESS. <br/> [Resolved type is '{0}']",
                                resolvedType.GetType().FullName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Append(" <strong>FAILED</strong>");
                        log.AppendLine("<p><strong>Error:</strong>" + ex.Message + "<p/>");
                        anyFail = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!anyFail)
            {
                log.AppendFormat("<h3>{0} c-tor arguments are Ok</h3>", controllerType.Name);
                try
                {
                    var resolvedCtor = EngineContext.Current.ContainerManager.Resolve(controllerType);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.AppendFormat(
                        "<h3 style='color:red'>Check {0} c-tor body there should be some logic which crashes and makes imposible to create an instance of the controller!</h3>", controllerType.Name);
                    log.AppendFormat("<b>Error:</b> {0}", ex.Message);
                    var innerException = ex.InnerException;
                    while (innerException != null)
                    {
                        log.AppendFormat("<br/><b>InnerException: </b>{0} <p>StackTrace: {1}</p>",
                            innerException.Message, innerException.StackTrace);
                        innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            log.AppendFormat("'{0}' created successfully", controllerType.FullName);
        }
        return log.ToString();
    }

    class DefaultControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
    {
        private readonly Func<IDependencyResolver> _resolverThunk;
        public DefaultControllerActivator()
            : this(null)
        {
        }
        public DefaultControllerActivator(IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            if (resolver == null)
            {
                this._resolverThunk = (() => DependencyResolver.Current);
                return;
            }
            this._resolverThunk = (() => resolver);
        }

        public bool CanCreate(Type controllerType)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = (IController)(this._resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType) ?? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception innerException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            IController result;
            try
            {
                result = (IController)(this._resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType) ?? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
            }
            catch (Exception innerException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    string.Format("An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '{0}'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.", controllerType), innerException);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

then define action method like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestCreateController(string controllerType)
    {
        return Content(ControllerActivatorHelper.TestCreateController(controllerType));
    }
```

**usage:**

[image]